# Шаблон ввода текста в input поле

Tags: input, html, html5, javascript

Скажите, есть ли стандартные средства для задания шаблона ввода текста в поле input, такое, чтоб поддерживалось большинством браузеров.

Например, должно быть одно поле ввода времени в формате: **ЧЧ:mm**.
В этом шаблоне нужно избежать ввода пользователем двоеточия.

Таким образом, конечным и правильным вариантов будет: **12:30**, **8:10** и т.п

Comment: Стандартный <input type="time"> не походит?

Comment: @jackrv, http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime   
@Oleg Ponomarchuk, используйте jquery плагин, коих полно, будете уверены в том, что работает как надо везде, к тому же сталить стандартный type=time тяжело.

Comment: Какой плагин посоветуете - удобный и с минимальным размером?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, посмотрите несколько. Все зависит от требований. Вполне возможно, кроме времени, вам понадобятся и другие варианты полей ввода. Я как-то использовал такой комбайн http://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот, может, поможет как-то](http://blainerobertson.net/content/?content=514).

Comment: Видимо, отчасти, там HTML5.